# Error with simple recursion in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I have this very simple recursion tried out in Java and I get an StackOverflow-Error everytime I run it. I do have a condition for the recursion to end, but it still won't work.

```
public class Rec {
    public static int arraySumRecursive(int[] a) {
        return sumRec(a, a.length-1);
    }

    private static int sumRec(int[] a, int i) {
        if(i == 0) {
            return a[i];
        } else {
            return a[i] + sumRec(a, i--);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test = {1, 7, 2, 5};
        System.out.println(arraySumRecursive(test));
    }
}
```

I just don't know what the problem is. When I go through the program with pen and paper it adds up, but it still won't work.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Thanks to everyone helping me out. I changed i-- to --i. I didn't know there was a difference!

Comment: I think it should be `--i` instead of `i--`. I might be wrong but I think what `i--` does is: Take the value `i` for the method call and THEN decrease it. `--i` does it the other way round.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `i--` to `i-1`. The expression `i--` actually returns `i`, and then decrements it after.

Alternatively, you could use the pre-decrement operator: `--i`. That way, it decrements `i` first, and then returns the value. However, you really don't need to mutate `i` here, so just using `i-1` probably makes the most sense.

Since `i--` returns the same value as `i` (and then decrements it afterward), this means your recursive call `sumRec(a, i--)` is equivalent to `sumRec(a, i)`. That's why you're getting infinite recursion (resulting in a StackOverflowError).

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
i--
```

evaluates to the *current* value of `i` and decrements it *afterward*.  So you're always sending the same value of `i` to the next recursive step.  Since `i` never changes, the recursion is infinite.

Just send the subtracted value exactly as you did in the initial call from `arraySumRecursive()`:

```
return a[i] + sumRec(a, i - 1);
```

(You *could* also use the decrement operator like this:  `--i`  However, it's entirely unnecessary to actually store the decremented value in `i` since you're *returning* on that same line and never using `i` afterward.  All you need to do is subtract the value, you don't need to update `i`.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if on Java is the same but in a lot of C based languages when you use `variable--` it will send its value then **after** it will decrement its value, so you should use `variable++` or else when you get to the line

> `return a[i] + sumRec(a, i--);`

it will call `sumRec` with the same value of i and after that decrease the value of `i` resulting in an StackOverflow

you could try `--i` or `i - 1`

Answer (score 1):

```
return a[i] + sumRec(a, --i);
```

or 
    return a[i] + sumRec(a, i-1);

Change i-- to --i,i.e., decrement first then call,otherwise i is not updated and it is always 3 thereby going into infinite loop causing stackoverflow  exception